# Cant get my link in my html to work

Tags: html, codepen

```
<form action="http://www.spacex.com/" method="get">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SpaceX</button>
</form>
```

Can't tell if it's my code that's wrong or the compiler off of CodePen. Anyways #save-my-code

Comment: describe what you want to do

Comment: You haven't told us what it is doing or what you want it to do. We can't read your mind or see your computer.

Comment: @SamM its not recognizing the link in my button. Can you not see the code

Comment: <form action="http://www.spacex.com/" method="get">
   
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SpaceX</button>
    </form>

Comment: @zladic91 Im trying to click my button and have it go to my link ive given in the form action

Comment: The code is in the question, yes. But you haven't told us what you expect the code to do or what the code is doing in codepen for you to say it's not working properly. Here's a good starting point for writing good questions that will yield better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SamM I thought it was clear that in my title I said "Cant get my link in my html to work" Sorry. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<a href="spacex.com/" class="btn btn-primary">SpaceX</a>
```

Comment: Okay instead of making a button and putting a link around it. Make a link that is a button? I will give this a try! Thanks I was confused because looking it up i found out you cant put an anchor tag around around a button in html5.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! Seriously that helped me out immensely. Cant believe it was that easy!